# DeleteAll with join?

Tags: php, yii2

В Yii2 ActiveRecord у модели есть статичный метод deleteAll. Как сделать удаление с джоином? Например я хочу вот так сделать:

```
delete article from article as a
left join user as u on a.user_id = u.id
where u.id is null
```

Есть модель Article, есть модель User.

```
// что-то вроде...
Article::deleteAll('inner join user as u on user_id = u.id where u.id is null');
```

Единственное что приходит в голову:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('delete :delete_table from :delete_table as d left join :user as u on d.user_id = u.id where u.id is null', [
    ':delete_table' => Article::tableName(),
    ':user' => User::tableName()
])->execute();
```

Comment: у вас целостность данных не обеспечена что ли, коли в статьях указывается не существующий id пользователя?

Comment: @teran Да. Так задумано.

Answer (score -1):

Наверно будет проще сделать выборку, собрать айдишники в массив и удалить. Пусть и в два запроса, но при этом код изящный, понятен каждому (и себе любимому) и не надо расписывать портянки sql.
Вряд ли это тот случай, когда необходим один запрос.

Comment: Плюс безболезненно можно переименовать таблицу (да, такие случаи бывают) и проще искать этот кусок кода в проекте.